# Django <object> is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

I am using https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities and i wanted to add city and country to my serializer.

This is my model:

```
from cities.models import Country, City

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, blank=True, null=True, default=None, related_name='city_of_location')
    geolocation = map_fields.GeoLocationField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
```

My views:

```
class LocationsView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Location.objects.order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = LocationsSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
class LocationsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    country = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='city.country')

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'geolocation', 'city', 'country']
```

When i'm trying to see if it works i'm getting:

```
<Country: Austria> is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: How are you "seeing if it works"?

Comment: could it be that you need GeoJSON serializer? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/serializers/ it would help seeing how you call it and your requirements.txt

Comment: @DanielRoseman i'm accessing to http://127.0.0.1:8000/locations/ this is where i should see the json, everything worked untill i added city and country in serializer

Comment: any ideea? anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `CountrySerializer` to serialize nested relation.

```
class CountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Country
         fields = '__all__' 

class LocationsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    number_of_rooms = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    country = CountrySerializer(source='city.country')

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'geolocation', 'city', 'country']
```

Or you can use [`PrimaryKeyRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) if you need only country id:

```
country = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='city.country')
```

Comment: i am getting now: AssertionError at /locations/
("Creating a ModelSerializer without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute has been deprecated since 3.3.0, and is now disallowed. Add an explicit fields = '__ all __' to the CountrySerializer serializer.",)

Comment: @NitaAlexandru sorry you need to specify fields in `CountrySerializer`, or jsut add `fields = '__all__' ` if you need all fields. See updates.